# Can I emit websocket event to not connected user?

Tags: websocket, socket.io

Client connects to a websocket-based api-gateway-server. Can i save some sort of reference/address of this client in order to send event to this client from another server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use socket.io and have client id you can send client event. You can proxy event between your servers and finally send it to the client. But client has to be connected on any of your servers. If the client is offline, you can't send event.

From docs https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room

> Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable,
>   unique identifier Socket#id. For your convenience, each socket
>   automatically joins a room identified by this id.

To send event to any room use:

```
io.to('some room').emit('some event');
```

you can do whatever you want with user id, put it anywhere you want but in the end **you have to send event using same user id to that user from the server which holds socket connection with user**

Comment: could you, pls, explain what exactly do you mean by "proxy event between your servers"?

Comment: you can do whatever you want with user id, put it anywhere you want but in the end you have to send event using same user id to that user from the server which holds socket connection with user

Comment: > you have to send event from the server which holds socket connection with user < that's what i needed. Could you add this into your answer, pls